# Angular CLI upgrade rewrote my angular-cli.json settings

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The upgrade of Angular CLI from 1.7.0 to 6.0.8 rewrote my .angular-cli.json settings. (It deleted .angular-cli.json and created angular.json.)

I'm not sure how it mapped the conversion.

I want to maintain the multiple "app" settings. I understand that now it is as "projects".

How do I implement the "ssr" values in the new angular.json?

This was the content of my .angular-cli.json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "MyProject"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ssr",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist-server",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      },
      "platform": "server"
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "build": {
      "progress": true
    }
  }
}
```

This is what it wrote for the new angular.json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "progress": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyProject-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyProject:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyProject",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Instead of trying to map the old config to the new one, I decided to just update angular.json according to what is written in https://angular.io/guide/universal#angular-cli-configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Include `the dist-server` in your new `angular-cli.json` like this

`"name": "ssr",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist-server",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      },
      "platform": "server"
    }
  ]`

and use `npm update` or `npm install` What really happen was your upgrading to higher version will cause a change to your `json` file which if the compiler detect old pattern overwrite it to fit the new pattern but if you are still having issues after that 
use this for proper upgrading without any problem      [Angular Upgrading](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: Rather than deal with migration and mapping, I decided to update the new angular.json, based on the Angular CLI configuration section at https://angular.io/guide/universal#angular-cli-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli has changed the json config and rename it to "angular.json" in the latest version. You can check the details of the new config [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace)

In the upgrade, it parse the old version to the new, so yo don't should have any problem. The only problem that I experienced is with the regulars expresions.

Comment: It didn't seem to bring over the multiple "app" settings I have. It should have mapped them to multiple projects.

Comment: I decided to instead review my angular.json file and update as necessary according to https://angular.io/guide/universal#angular-cli-configuration.